# Moving things inside a two-dimensional array in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a clone of 2048 for a cs class in as3, and I'm having trouble with moving blocks around. I basically declare a 4x4 array:

```
var tiles:Array = new Array(new Array(4), new Array(4), new Array(4), new Array(4));
```

I set it all to empty string at the beginning:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        tiles[i][j] = '';
    }
}
```

I also have a display function in order to display the array on the frame:

```
function display():void{
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(tiles[i][j] != ''){
                tiles[i][j].x = 50 + (107 * j)
                tiles[i][j].y = 50 + (107 * i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a keydown event to move the tiles:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        if(tiles[i][j] != ''){
            switch (event.keyCode){
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                    tiles[i][0] = tiles[i][j]
                    break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                    tiles[i][3] = tiles[i][j]
                    break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                    tiles[0][j] = tiles[i][j]
                    break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                    tiles[3][j] = tiles[i][j]
                    break;
            }
            tiles[i][j] = ''
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to set a new tile to the equivalent of the old tile, then set the old tile to `''`, but for some reason it sets both the new tile and the old tile to `''`! I'm not sure what is going on here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where do you set the value to anything different than an empty string in your code?

Comment: @null Outside of the movement function, of course. 2048 spawns new non-empty tiles each move.

Comment: You are iterating movement wrongly. You need to move all tiles to a certain side, so you should iterate from that side - if up, you should iterate Y from 0 to 3 (provided 3 is lower than 0) and if down, you should iterate Y from 3 to 0, otherwise you'll lose tiles in process. Also you should skip empty tiles, that is if you have 2 at (1,0) and 4 at (1,3) and process an upward move, your 4 should end up at (1,1). And you have to merge equal tiles into one bigger tile, and this all should be processed in a movement routine.

Comment: Since this routine is more than half of your project, you should do that yourself. In this code your second error, except from totally wrong movement processing, is that `tiles[i][j] = ''` is processed on *every* tile instead of only those that were moved, resulting in a cleared board.